# text with .format in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, format, jupyter

I am trying to use the code below in Jupyter Notebook. But when I run it it throws an error on the line that has the text.format. I can not solve this error in any way ... Anyone have any idea what might be happening?

```
disp_med = 69.658
perf_med = 85.6974
qual_med = 95.654
oee_16 = (disp_med * perf_med * qual_med) / 10000

arq_escrita = open('oee_2016.txt', 'w')
texto = '''var data=[{"category":"Indice OEE","num":{0}, "num2": 100},
          {"category":"Qualidade","num":{1}, "num2": 100},
          {"category":"Performance","num":{2}, "num2": 100},
          {"category":"Disponibilidade","num":{3}, "num2": 100}];'''
texto = texto.format('{:.0f}'.format(oee_16),'{:.0f}'.format(qual_med), '{:.0f}'.format(perf_med), '{:.0f}'.format(disp_med))
arq_escrita.write(texto)
arq_escrita.close()
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

it seems like your error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 11, in <module>
    texto = texto.format('{:.0f}'.format(oee_16),'{:.0f}'.format(qual_med), '{:.0f}'.format(perf_med), '{:.0f}'.format(disp_med))
KeyError: '"category"'
```

You can't use format in the provided text as it can't find out which of `{something}`'s are to be formatted and which are ignored (so it expects you to provide a value for "Category"), consider generating the result by actually creating the data you provided in python and then turn it into text using the json library.

**Better solution as provided in comments:** 
Escape the `{}` by doubling them up (`{{}}`) for the parts that don't need replacement.

Comment: Or you can double up the `{}` in order to escape them: `{{"category":"Indice OEE","num":{0}, "num2": 100}}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your string contains braces (`{` / `}`) as part of the json, so `format` thinks that these should be replaced. You can resolve the issue by replacing these braces with double braces `{{` / `}}`:

```
texto = '''var data=[{{"category":"Indice OEE","num":{0}, "num2": 100\}},
          {{"category":"Qualidade","num":{1}, "num2": 100}},
          {{"category":"Performance","num":{2}, "num2": 100}},
          {{"category":"Disponibilidade","num":{3}, "num2": 100}}];'''
```